# Finding mode of unique array combination in the rows of 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, mode

I have a 2d numpy array which I'm trying to return the mode array along `axis = 0` (rows). However, I would like to return the most frequent unique row combination.  And not the three modes for all three columns which is what scipy stats mode does. The desired output in the example below would be `[9,9,9]`, because thats the most common unique row. Thanks

```
from scipy import stats

arr1 = np.array([[2,3,4],[2,1,5],[1,2,3],[2,4,4],[2,8,2],[2,3,1],[9,9,9],[9,9,9]])

stats.mode(arr1, axis = 0)
```

output:

```
ModeResult(mode=array([[2, 3, 4]]), count=array([[5, 2, 2]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the numpy unique funtion and return counts.

```
unique_arr1, count = np.unique(arr1,axis=0, return_counts=True)
unique_arr1[np.argmax(count)]
```

output:

```
array([9, 9, 9])
```

np.unique return the unique array in sorted order, which means it is guranteed that last one is the maximum. you could simply do:

```
out = np.unique(arr1,axis=0)[-1]
```

however, I do not know for what purpose you want to use this but just to mention that you could have all counts just in case you want to verify or account for multiple rows with same counts as well.

**Update**
given additional information that this is for images (which could be big) and most  importantly second dim could fit in a int (either each values is uin8 or 16) could fir in int32 or 64. (considering of values of each pixel in uint8):

```
pixel, count = np.unique(np.dot(arr, np.array([2**16,2**8,1])),  return_counts=True)
pixel = pixel[np.argmax(count)]
b,g, r, = np.ndarray((3,), buffer=pixel, dtype=np.uint8)
```

This could result in a big speedup.

Comment: thank you! it does exactly what i want it to.  just fyi, i'm using it to find the most frequent RGB values. These red , green , blue values are extracted from an image and i'm trying to find the most common color among it.   cheers

Comment: you are welcome, if you are using this for big image, since every pixel could fit in a int just creat a array of int then look at the frequency of each pixel, that could be a lot faster. I will edit my answer to include this

Comment: ok thx, useful for the images. altho i'll need to go throught it later to understand properly.